# Can't get flexbox to vertically align my content in the center

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I just started learning HTML and CSS and have come across this problem where justify-content wont vertically center my elements. My flex-direction is column and even with it as default row and using align-items my elements just wont budge vertically, but horizontally it always works. I'm really just trying to center the text both vertically and horizontally using flex. Also I'm using Firefox and I've tested on Chrome too. Here's the HTML

```
<div class="brands">
    <section class="YSL">
        <h1>Yves Saint Laurent</h1>
    </section>

    <section class="LV">
        <h1>Louis Vuitton</h1>
    </section>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS for the elements:

```
.brands{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.YSL{
    color: black;
    margin: 0;
}

.LV{
    color: black;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: `html,
body,
.brands {
  height: 100%;
}`

Comment: your flex container has only as much height as needed to fit the contents. You need to set height on the flex container. See this [demo](https://jsbin.com/rupumurehu/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Thank You! This has fixed my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your HTML and CSS slightly.

I think this does exactly what you wanted, let me know if there is anything I can improve:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.brands {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="brands">
  <div class="row">
    Yves Saint Laurent
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    Louis Vuitton
  </div>
</div>
```